# linux: get error 500 at running cgi-bin module in apache, not from ssh

Tags: linux, apache, cgi, cgi-bin

When I login in ssh and run my cgi : everything seems ok

```
./modulev2.cgi 
Content-type: text/html
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
```

When I try to call it through http: http://www.capuccino.fr/cgi-bin/modulev2.cgi
I got a nasty:

```
Internal Server Error
```

I tried to put chmod777 on cgi-bin, on home etc.. with no success

When looking at logs:
cgi.log:

```
[2013-07-22 11:21:12]: uid: (1000/capuccin) gid: (100/users) cmd: modulev2.cgi
[2013-07-22 11:21:12]: target uid/gid (1000/100) mismatch with directory (510/100) or program (0/0)
```

and error_log

```
[Mon Jul 22 11:21:03 2013] [error] [client 91.7.112.187] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Jul 22 11:21:03 2013] [error] [client 91.7.112.187] Premature end of script headers: modulev2.cgi
```

I also tried to change chown and got this in cgi.log

```
[2013-07-22 11:56:36]: target uid/gid (1000/100) mismatch with directory (510/100) or program (1000/100)
[2013-07-22 11:56:39]: uid: (1000/capuccin) gid: (100/users) cmd: modulev2.cgi
```

Any idea on how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like wrong file/folder permissions.

Try to set permission to *775* and ensure that the owner of the file and folder is correct. Set owner to the same your webserver (something like *www-data* or *apache*).